# Dynamic tag in JSON

Tags: json, typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I am generating one JSON file and I have a variable of the below type in TypeScript:

```ts
export interface Rules{
  name: string,
  condition: string,
}
```

I want to parse the 'Rule' type in JSON in the below format:

```ts
"dataRetentionRules": {
    "RULE_1": {
        "name": "test123",
             "condition": "RetentionStartDate"
        },
    "RULE_2": {
        "name": "test456",
        "condition": "RetentionEndDate"
    }       
}
```

How can I make this rule tag dynamic? I mean how do I parse this `"RULE_1"`, `"RULE_2"` tag? Since tags are supposed to be constant I believe. How can I achieve the above format?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the typescript [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) built-in type.  Behind the scenes you are using the principles of [index types and mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

But all that you really need to know it this: `Record<string, Rules>` defines an object whose keys are strings and whose values are instances of `Rules`.

Your JSON object can be described by

```
interface HasRetentionRules {
  dataRetentionRules: Record<string, Rules>
}
```

Note that this is asserting that *any* string key corresponds to a `Rules` object and it does not check for invalid keys, so you need to check for invalid keys yourself.  Alternatively, you can use `Partial<Record<string, Rules>>` which states that any string key has a value which is of type `Rules` or `undefined`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoFcA2EDOyDeAUMsiHALYQBcyOYUoA5gDTHIID2IAJsGMFxp0GIFoQC%20hQmACeABxQAROGDioIkcAJAZseALxoInKNwA8wpszRZcAPimhIsRCgAScHOs38uu3ARs3CpqGhBafrY4NOom5pai1v44DpKEnCB0yABWOILIHl5hETpRyIZEJABEware4b6lelU0lSTIVagAqgAyAKIA%20gCMLYHt4x1klKNVkHRDAEwAzFWsE%201VGbyNM-UlAMqqUGDKkFVsJOJrG939AwujbetVUxAzc2AALACsAGyrFwmmy4220u2KjT6PFOb0B4nWyDYkjSAHoUbQABYcLDcZAAIxQHBgyFkChsenSXCycHKOTyIAAdLVQj5tMkANqdXqDEYAXQA3EA)